# how to reassemble tcp and decode http info in c code?

Tags: c, networking, pcap

I am working with libpcap to check http info. libpcap can not reassemble tcp segment.
there are many corner cases to deal manually. I also read wireshark source code. It's too big.
Does have any open source code can reassemble tcp and disect http data in c?

Comment: Writing a robust TCP reassembler is a non-trivial task. A very mature one ships with the [Bro  network security monitor](http://www.bro-ids.org). It ships with a variety of application-layer parsers, including HTTP. The reassembler is written C++, but might be a good source of inspiration. Application-layer protocols are specified declaratively with [BinPac](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/binpac.IMC06.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Have hacked code of driftnet, tcpflow, pcap etc. earlier.

**tcpflow** can re-assemble dumps from ie tcpdump. A "typical" chain of work could be:

```
$ tcpdump -nnieth0 -w dump.raw
# dump dum dump
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp
tmp/$ tcpflow -r ../dump.raw
# This joins the transfers into separate files
# Now one can investigate each transfere from those separate files
# Next join them to one:
tmp/$ cat * > ../dump.flow
tmp/$ cd ..
# Extract some data
$ foremost -i dump.flow
```

Believe you can find some useful lines in the source-code for these.

Else:
A HTTP parsing library: [HTTP Parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser)

Comment: many tcp  re-assesamble code on web. But where is decoding http info from tcp stream?

Comment: What do you mean by http info? Headers and such? As in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: sorry for my confusion. English is not my native language. I only want to get some tcp and http info in c code. such ad src IP/port dst IP/port.  http xforward-flag ...

Comment: You get src / dst IP and port with libpcap. See ie http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c , As for http headers the structure is well described in the standard: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 , As for code the tools I mentioned above has source on-line. Other code to look at would be ie libcurl and wget. (That is how I understood your question; that you wanted projects with open code handling this.)

Comment: Thanks. src IP/port dst IP/port. I use libnids to get them. libcurl and wget is good start point.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is download wireshark software open pcap file or live capture it. after that right click any packet and go to "follow tcp stream"...you will see your http data in opened window.

If you want to build a program from scratch.-
A pcap file structure for tcp transaction is something like this:
[pcap_file_header]
    for each packet
        [pcap_packet] --this contains packet len info
        [ip_header]----usually of size 20 or more
        [tcp_header]--usually of size 20 or more
        [packet] ---len stored in pcap packet header

Now to read the info, first get your pcap file in stream pointer.
Read packet file header(google for various type of struct)
 
start a loop
    for each packet
        read pcap_phdr from file or stream
        add offset of ip_hdr length and tcp hdr length 
        for example pointer=pointer+20(for ip)+20(for tcp)
the pointer should be pointing to your data 
so just give read pcap_phdr.caplen amount of byte and print it character by character.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest TCP/IP stack I know of, which is open source is [uIP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uip-stack/) but it is a bit odd, as it is designed for extremely small systems (microcontrollers)

Another small Open Source TCP/IP stack, which is a bit more traditional is [lwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/)

Comment: I check uip. it does not support http protocol. I want to decode http info.

Comment: how it is libnids?  Libnids offers IP defragmentation, TCP stream assembly functions.